# ¿Es posible hacer que una foreign key referencie a 2 primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

miren tengo 3 tablas

Boleta (
codBoleta -- PK
)

Factura (
codFactura -- pk
)

Venta (
codVenta -- pk
codComprobante --fk  Quiero que el codComprobante pueda referenciar o bien un código de factura o de boleta
)

Comment: Venta es para una relación muchos a muchos?, conviene leas [ask] y de paso hagas el [tour] pues para poder responder hacen falta por ejemplo las reglas de negocio

Comment: Y si tienes una tabla que guarde comprobantes con un campo idTipo que identifique diferentes tipos de comprobante (1-boleta, 2-factura) e identificas los atributos comunes a los comprobantes?

Answer (score 0):

Se puede referenciar a dos tablas con la misma columna. Vamos a verlo.

```
Create table Boleta
 (
  codBoleta      int primary key
, codComprobante int unique
 );

create table Factura
(
  codFactura     int primary key
, codComprobante int unique
);

Create table Venta
(
  codVenta       int primary key
, codComprobante int
, constraint fk_Venta_Boleta foreign key(codComprobante) references Boleta(codComprobante)
, constraint fk_Venta_Factura foreign key(codComprobante) references Factura(codComprobante)
);
go

Insert into Boleta(codBoleta
                 , codComprobante)
values
       ( 1, 1 );

Insert into Factura(codFactura
                  , codComprobante)
values
       ( 1, 1 );

Insert into Venta(codVenta
                , codComprobante)
values
       ( 1, 1 );
go
```

Ahora bien, para la pregunta que planteas, solo tienes que tener en cuenta las limitaciones que plantean las fk.

- No es necesario que una restricción de clave externa esté vinculada
  únicamente a una restricción de clave principal de otra tabla;
  también puede definirse para que haga referencia a las columnas de
  una restricción UNIQUE de otra tabla.

Pero si insertas en:

```
Insert into Boleta(codBoleta
                 , codComprobante)
values
       ( 2, 2 );
Insert into Venta(codVenta
                , codComprobante)
values
       ( 2, 2 );

Mens. 547, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 46
Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY 'fk_Venta_Factura'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'T', tabla 'dbo.Factura', column 'codComprobante'.
Se terminó la instrucción.
```

Incumples la restricción.

Lo mismo ocurre si haces el caso contrario.

```
Insert into Factura(codFactura
                  , codComprobante)
values
       ( 3, 3 );
go
Insert into Venta(codVenta
                , codComprobante)
values
       ( 3, 3 );

Mens. 547, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 56
Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY 'fk_Venta_Boleta'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'T', tabla 'dbo.Boleta', column 'codComprobante'.
Se terminó la instrucción.
```

Y tiene todo el sentido porque cada restricción es única y se comprueba por si misma.

Dentro de las posibilidades que nos brinda el motor, está la de deshabilitar las restricciones en inserciones o updates.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Venta] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_Venta_Boleta]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Venta NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_Venta_Factura]
GO
```

Y a partir de ese momento se puede insertar.

```
Insert into Venta(codVenta
                , codComprobante)
values
       ( 2, 2 ), (3,3);
```

Aunque yo me pensaría si mi modelo de tablas es el correcto.

[No check constraints](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/tables/disable-check-constraints-with-insert-and-update-statements?view=sql-server-ver15)